# DIV Vertical Scroll bar on left

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to put DIV's Vertical Scroll bar on left of the div with css? what about jscript?

Comment: People (using LTR documents anyway) expect scrollbars on the right. You really should leave them there. (And if you are dealing with a RTL language, then the scrollbar will be on the left anyway, unless you've got your markup for the language and text direction wrong)

Comment: @Quentin: Chrome always shows vertical scroll bars at the right side.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add a pseudo-scrollbar anywhere you want with [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) and this plug-in: [JScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com)

Comment: jQuery is not mandatory here. Before you go with it, check latkinson's pure CSS solution (just below)

Answer (score 57):

I had a simple use case so opted for a simple css solution:

```
<div style="direction: rtl; height: 250px; overflow: scroll;">
  <div style="direction: ltr; padding: 3px;">
     Content goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome but it seems not to be working on Safari (testing it on Safari 5.1.7 right now and the scrollbar is on the right).

Answer (score 10):

Okay, so, I wrote a jQuery plugin to give you a completely-native-looking left scroll bar.

[**Left Scrollbar Hack Demo**](http://thirdroute.com/projects/left-scrollbars/)

Here's how it works:

1. Inject an inner `div` inside the pane to allow calculation of the content width (`content_width`). Then, using this, the native scrollbar width can be calculated: `scrollbar_width = parent_width - content_width - horizontal_padding` .
2. Make two different `divs` inside the pane, both filled with the content.

   - One's purpose is being a "poser". It's used *solely* for the scrollbar. Using a negative left margin, the plugin pulls it left so that only the scrollbar is in view (the content of this `div` is clipped off at the edge).
   - The other `div` is used to actually house the visible scrolling content.
3. Now, it's time to bind the two together. Every 50ms (`window.setInterval`), the `scrollTop` offset from the "poser" `div` is applied to the visible, scrolling content `div`. So, when you scroll up or down with the scrollbar on the *left*, the scroll offset gets applied back on the `div` with the visible content.

This explanation probably sucks and there's actually a quite a bit more to it that I didn't describe, but, without further ado, here it is:

```
$.fn.leftScrollbar = function(){
    var items = $(this);
    $(function(){
        items.each(function(){
            var e = $(this);
            var content = e.html();
            var ie = !jQuery.support.boxModel;
            var w = e[ie?'innerWidth':'width'](), h = e[ie?'innerHeight':'height']();
            //calculate paddings
            var pad = {};
            $(['top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left']).each(function(i, side){
                pad[side] = parseInt(e.css('padding-' + side).replace('px',''));
            });
            //detect scrollbar width
            var xfill = $('<div>').css({margin:0, padding:0, height:'1px'});
            e.append(xfill);
            var contentWidth = xfill.width();
            var scrollerWidth = e.innerWidth() - contentWidth - pad.left - pad.right;
            e.html('').css({overflow:'hidden'});
            e.css('padding', '0');

            var poserHeight = h - pad.top - pad.bottom;
            var poser = $('<div>')
                .html('<div style="visibility:hidden">'+content+'</div>')
                .css({
                    marginLeft: -w+scrollerWidth-(ie?0:pad.left*2),
                    overflow: 'auto'
                })
                .height(poserHeight+(ie?pad.top+pad.bottom:0))
                .width(w);

            var pane = $('<div>').html(content).css({
                width: w-scrollerWidth-(ie?0:pad.right+pad.left),
                height: h-(ie?0:pad.bottom+pad.top),
                overflow: 'hidden',
                marginTop: -poserHeight-pad.top*2,
                marginLeft: scrollerWidth
            });

            $(['top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left']).each(function(i, side){
                 poser.css('padding-'+side, pad[side]);
                 pane.css('padding-'+side, pad[side]);
            });
            e.append(poser).append(pane);

            var hRatio = (pane.innerHeight()+pad.bottom) / poser.innerHeight();
            window.setInterval(function(){
                pane.scrollTop(poser.scrollTop()*hRatio);
            }, 50);
        });
    });
};
```

Once you've included jQuery and this plugin in the page, apply the left scroll bar:

```
$('#scrollme').leftScrollbar();
```

Replace `#scrollme` with the CSS selector to the element(s) you wish to apply left scrollbars to.

(and, obviously, this degrades nicely)

Comment: instead a setInterval, try to add an event listener for DOMAttrModified (or onpropertychange event for IE)

Comment: @jcm: Fixed! Sorry about that.

Comment: You should consider using [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com) or [Codepen](http://www.codepen.io) (or any service like this two) to showcase demos. And as said before, there is no real need for jquery here, considering the pure CSS solution from latkinson. Rebuilding scrollbars or other native UI items in jquery is clearly an overkill.

Comment: @Gfra54 Thanks for the wisdom – this is from 2009

Comment: this also is in Google when you look for that particular subject, even in 2015. (and the last dead link warning is from 2014)