# HTML element scrollbar on the left

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DIV Vertical Scroll bar on left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455708/div-vertical-scroll-bar-on-left)

is there a way with css or js to show the scrollbar of an element on the left instead of on the right? i don't need a crossbrowser way i need it only on Firefox.

Comment: It will be on the left if you are using a RTL language. If you are using a LTR language then you violate a very very standard convention and make it much harder to use.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Doesn't it go against convention set by every OS and piece of software out there?

Comment: Yes i know it but it's not for a public site so i dont' care about the standard. I need it because i have a very large element with fixed height, so if i have to scroll down its content i must do the horizontal scroll first, but if i can put the scrollbar on the right i can scroll vertically without moving horizontally.

Comment: you might be interested in http://www.askvg.com/how-to-move-scrollbar-from-right-to-left-in-mozilla-firefox-30/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the direction to be left-to-right, but still want to violate every expectation a user has to scrollbars, then you can hack it using javascript.
Simply create a 1px wide div on the left side of your content. Have it be the same height as the content which you want to scroll. Then hook up an `onscroll` event to that div and whenever the user scrolls that div, you can scroll the content area manually.

Some further tips: main content area needs to have `overflow:hidden` and you can use negative values for `margin-top` to fake the scrolling.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<textarea dir="rtl">
```

or

```
<body dir="rtl">
```

or

```
<html dir="rtl">
```

Comment: Note that this can be done in CSS too: `.something { direction:rtl }`