# Scrollbar on the left

Tags: css

I currently use the following to make the scrollbar appear on the left, rather than the right:

HTML:

```
<div class="leftscrollbar"><div>Content here</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.leftscrollbar {
    overflow:auto;
    transform:scaleX(-1);
}
.leftscrollbar>div {
    transform:scaleX(-1);
}
```

It works great, but is there a better way than using two transforms?

Comment: I had no idea you could do this

Comment: Why? `:'(` ...try http://stackoverflow.com/a/2772401/139010 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/7214972/139010

Comment: possible duplicate of [DIV Vertical Scroll bar on left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455708/div-vertical-scroll-bar-on-left)

Comment: To answer why: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/hgzla9V.png). The entire "canvas" is scrollable, but the content itself is all over there on the left. Having the scrollbar with the content makes sense, doesn't it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use the [`direction`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html) property,

```
direction: rtl;
```

Set `direction: rtl` on the parent element and `direction: ltr` on the child element:

```css
.leftscrollbar {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  direction: rtl;
}

.leftscrollbar>div {
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftscrollbar">
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit. Pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus. Integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum. Neque egestas congue quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus euismod. Orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet. Pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus. Sit amet dictum sit amet justo donec enim. Ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget duis. Orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor. Elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed. Adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui. Adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et. Bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit. Lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in massa tempor nec. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales. Aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet purus. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus. Turpis massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit. Neque vitae tempus quam pellentesque. Elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi. Tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium. Eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et. Amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada. 
  </div>
</div>
```