# Scrollbar / Direction issue

Tags: css, scrollbar, right-to-left

this is my first post here.
I have Code for displaying the scrollbar on the left side of the div:

```
body 
{
    direction:ltr;
}
```

and

```
<div style="direction:rtl;">
```

and the text is still left to right
everything works great in IE
but in firefox and safari it displays still on right side

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455708/div-vertical-scroll-bar-on-left ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting any issues in firefox. Have you considered:

1) using a class instead of a style via the div (ignore if you're just using style for example purposes)

2) using text-align, which has a very similar end result.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you are using the correct Doctype, as IE might display incorrectly without the correct declaration.