# How to move a div's scrollbar to the left in safari/chrome?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, direction

I have a div and the requirement on it is to move the scrollbar from the right side to the left side.  I've accomplished this in FF and IE with a `direction:rtl;` css declaration.  Safari and Chrome both seem to ignore this and still put the scrollbar on the right side. Is there a way to get it on the left side in both Safari and Chrome? Thanks!

(Also I cannot convince the people involved with this to have the scrollbar on the right side like it usually is, so I just need a solution to get it on the left.)

Comment: I'm not aware of any native functionality in Webkit browsers (Safari, Chrome, etc) to do this. Personally, I would use jScrollPane or a plugin like this.

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455708/div-vertical-scroll-bar-on-left

Comment: yeah jscrollpane is probably the way to go but man oh man do I hate custom scrollbars. You will notice a difference in performance every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In lieu of a full-fledged JS plugin like jscrollpane, you could achieve the desired effect with a 'dummy' div and a few lines of JavaScript. This jsFiddle I whipped up shows the working effect:

http://jsfiddle.net/rtceC/

You may, however, want to add a few lines to register a scroll wheel event over the pseudo-scrolling content div and adjust scrollTop for the dummy (and thereby for the content itself) accordingly.