# Chrome shows vertical scrollbar at the right side when using direction:rtl

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit, right-to-left

When I put `style='direction: rtl;'` the vertical scrollbar should switch sides and show on the left instead of right. This is how it works in IE and FF, but in Chrome it remains on the right.

Is it a known bug? Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [known webkit bug](https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-unassigned/2011-April/314538.html). The scroll will render on the right in Safari, as well.

There's an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455708/div-vertical-scroll-bar-on-left) that has several different workarounds, including the jQuery plugin [jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html) and [a native-looking hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455708/div-vertical-scroll-bar-on-left/1456674#1456674).

Comment: +1 for the thorough answer - although if RTL users are using WebKit they may have gotten used to the incorrect behaviour having seen it on so many other websites, so it might be worth letting it be wrong until the WebKit fix makes it work correctly for all websites.

Comment: @Sohnee - as an RTL user myself (hebrew) i can say that it's pretty much annoying. you expect the scrollbar not to come "before" the text. sometimes its not really important, but in some situations it's as annoying as hell.

Comment: @JoshSmith - what's the status of this bug? do u know when it's going to be fixed? (i couldn't understand it from the link you provided)

Comment: @EladKatz - I agree it's wrong and needs to be fixed, but it needs to be fixed in WebKit, not just on individual websites.