# Set Browser Vertical Scrollbar Left or Right

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

Is there a CSS or JS solution to move browser's vertical scroll bar? It is said [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/954353), that since 2006, Firefox supports

```
layout.scrollbar.side;
```

,which at least latest Firefox versions don't.

IE pays attention to the direction of the :

```
body:{
  direction:rtl;
}
```

Is it possible to do the same for latest versions of Firefox,Chrome?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DIV Vertical Scroll bar on left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455708/div-vertical-scroll-bar-on-left)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347532/how-to-position-a-div-scrollbar-on-the-left-hand-side

Comment: Absolutely not, That's a <div>'s scrollbar matter.